# Showing a large amount of HTML alternative content with swfobject & swffit flash site

Tags: html, css, flash, swfobject

I have a full flash site which uses swfobject to embed it 100% height and width. I'm using swffit to force a browser scroll bar for pages with a large amount of content. This is all fine and works perfectly. I also have the content in HTML format, as alternative content and this also works apart from in order to get the flash swfobject to work I need to add the overflow = hidden in the CSS, like:

```
html{
height: 100%;
overflow:hidden; 
}
#content{
height: 100%;
}
```

This then stops the scroll bar showing when the alternative content is shown.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know SWFFit but why do you need the `overflow: hidden` in the first place? Won't it work without?

The only workaround that comes to mind is to define two classes, one with, one without `overflow: hidden`, and change the class of the `html` element programmatically from within Flash by triggering some Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, I don't quite know why the overflow-hidden either. Maybe it's simply missing `margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%` on the `body`?

Comment: Thanks Pekka, I feel stupid. I couldnt remember why, but I was adamant that I needed the overflow hidden setting. But I didnt.

Comment: overflow:hidden fixes a scrollbar issue in IE6 for SWFs that are scaled to 100% height/width in the browser. probably 90% of the time you won't need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change a page's CSS or content based on the success of a SWFObject embed, use the callback function feature in SWFObject 2.2.

For dynamic publishing, it looks like this:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var embedHandler = function (e){
};

swfobject.embedSWF("mymovie.swf", "targetID", "550", "400", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, embedHandler);
```

In your situation, if you needed to remove overflow:hidden from the HTML element, you could do this:

```
var flashvars = {};
var params = {};
var attributes = {};
var embedHandler = function (e){
   //If embed fails
   if(!e.success){
      document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.overflow = "auto";
   }
};

swfobject.embedSWF("mymovie.swf", "targetID", "550", "400", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, embedHandler);
```

This callback function feature is only available in SWFObject 2.2.